# FFmpeg transcode piped mp4 with MOOV at end - but I can read it twice

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, mp4, pipe, transcode

I need to transcoding an MP4 file using that I can only access via a stream. The MOOV atom is at the end of the file. I do not have the ability to seek to a specific part of the file, only read a pipe start-to-end. However I can read the stream multiple times.

In theory, there is no reason that I cannot transcode the file: I can read through the stream once, get the MOOV atom, store it, and finish. Then I can read the file again and transcode it as if the MOOV atom was at the start, since I know what it is.

Is there any way for me to achieve this with FFmpeg? If not, is there any other tool that could do it?

Comment: My issue is now resolved, but it is not an answer to my question because it was solved by removing one of the constraints that I thought existed but actually didn't. I said `I do not have the ability to seek to a specific part of the file` - this was not true. I was accessing the file via a URL, and my real constraint was just that I couldn't store the whole file locally at once. By simply using that URL as the input to ffmpeg instead of the stream, ffmpeg was able to seek through the file as needed without downloading it. Leaving the question up because this isn't an answer to it as written.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fragmented MP4 by setting one of the fragmentation options in ffmpeg. Then there would be no seek to an offset in the output.